# How do you set a model with repeating variables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model

Objective: Use the model to show total sales of an id and total sales difference for multiple periods.

Issue: Using MVC4 I have a model for a report that displays total sales. I know I can add a variable for each additional period, but I have many periods that I'd like to use to compare and show a difference. How can this be done avoiding needless repetition?

```
public class Report
{
     public long ID { get; set }

    public long TotalSales { get; set}

    public long TotalSales2 { get; set}

    public long TotalSalesDiff { get; set} 

 }
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions and/or comments

Comment: When is it determined how many periods you want to check

Comment: The number of periods is determined at the time the report is requested. Essentially the report allows you to choose an ID or all the IDs and then select a To and From period from a drop down list. If the drop down list is selected a second set of drop downs appears up to a maximum 10 drop downs.

Comment: In other words I'm looking for a way to avoid using a public long TotalSales 2, TotalSales 3, .... TotalSales10

Comment: I don't think you can dynamically add Model properties

Comment: I thought not, but had to ask

Comment: Why not a List<long> TotalSalesN from which values can be added and removed based on user input?

Comment: that makes sense and then I can use a for loop to go through that list to generate columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your scenario you have two option either create a dictionary that can create properties or use  Dynamic object class

For dictionary

```
 public class DictionaryProperty
 {

      Dictionary<string, object> Yourproperties = new Dictionary<string, object>( );

      public object this[ string name ]
      {
            get
            {
                 if ( Yourproperties.ContainsKey( name ) )
                 {
                      return Yourproperties[ name ];
                 }
                 return null;
            }
            set
            {
                 Yourproperties[ name ] = value;
            }
      }

 }
```

}

And for the Dynamic object please refer following link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx

cheers

I don’t have enough points to add a comments that’s the why I make this is an answer.