# C#: Dynamic add field to class

Tags: c#, dynamic

I search on Google but the result is misunderstand.
This is a code flow:

```
public class Store
{
     public dynamic GetList(List<string> propertyFields)
     {
          // Body here
          // for in list propertyFields. Such as: ["Code", "Name", "Address", ...]
          // dynamic result = ...
          // result.Code = "value", result.Name = "abc", result.Address = "homeless", result.... = "..."
          // return result
     }
}
```

Method returns a dynamic object.
propertyFields is a list of fields name. When I pass 4 strings in list, dynamic has 4 property fields with value (later).

When I call this method:

```
Store store = new Store(); 
var rs = store.GetList(["Code","Name","Address"])
Console.WriteLine(rs[0].Code)
```

That is my point. 

**My question**: Is it possible to do that in C#?

Comment: check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545397/how-do-you-set-a-model-with-repeating-variables/23552394#23552394

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create dynamic properties in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947241/how-do-i-create-dynamic-properties-in-c)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have confused `dynamic`, which is a compiler feature that means "defer type analysis of uses of this object until runtime" with `ExpandoObject` which means "an object that can have properties added at runtime".

It is an understandable confusion; many languages that lack static type checking also have expando objects.

Answer (score 4):

You need to take a look to ExpandoObject class.

Here is more detailed answer to your question:

[Dynamic class creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698619/dynamic-class-creation)

[What are the true benefits of ExpandoObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653046/what-are-the-true-benefits-of-expandoobject)